# Store everything from a vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant box (ubuntu 16.04) for development, and I made several `apt install` and some change to config files (`.ini`, `.cnf`, etc.) after initializing it. Now, I am OK with this box and its content. I want to save it before destroying everything by mistake.

I read [this](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html) but I'm not sure to understand if it's really what I need. Does a snapshot store eveything? I mean does it save each installed programs, each edited conf and each files added in the shared `/vagrant` dir?

[Doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/snapshot.html) speaks about "environment", that's why I am not sure it's what I want (side question if it's what I want: should I `vagrant snapshot push` or `vagrant snapshot save`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options to achieve what you want:

- If you want to share the same environment with your teammates, you can package your VM as a new vagrant box (as explained by kikitux) so you can upload this box and your teammates will be install to spin a new VM based on your box (so they will have equivalent system)
- If are able to put the changes you made into some scripts, a better option is to use [vagrant provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html) (it can be bash script or more sophisticated chef/puppet system) - Its nice if you need to apply the same customization on another system, if you want to upgrade ubuntu for example, you can just apply the same provisioning script.
- third, if you're local and just want to use that as a backup solution, the new feature vagrant snapshot is what you need. This has been a great addition in 1.8 version and does exactly what you need here.

> Does a snapshot store eveything? I mean does it save each installed programs, each edited conf and each files added in the shared /vagrant dir?

Yep ! all this - I just share my use cases : I create an oracle database VM and import dump files and after I execute a series of test. I take a snapshot before I run the tests and I can easily revert back to the previous status and rerun tests the next day on the same base box. When I `pop` the snapshot I get the exact same status (whole VM, oracle installed, dump imported) as before I run the test suite.

> side question if it's what I want: should I vagrant snapshot push or vagrant snapshot save?

I use `push` and `pop` because I only need to keep 1 snapshot and always revert back to this snapshot. If you need to keep snapshots at different times (for example one per day) you need to use `save` as you will specifically give a name for the snapshot you're taking.

Pay attention to this

> **Warning**: If you are using `push` and `pop`, avoid using `save` and `restore` which are unsafe to mix.

Answer (score 0):

vagrant package box should help you to create a new box.

Just note that since vagrant 1.7+ by default vagrant will change the ssh insecure keys, so if just package the box, it wont be able to connect on the next start up.

add the content of:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub

into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

and then run:
chmod 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh